# Azure - Fault / Update Domain

Tags: azure

Im struggling to understand the concept of Fault / Update Domain in Azure, any help would be appreciated.
I have provisioned 2 VMs under the same Availability Set with 2 Fault Domain and 2 Update Domain respectively :

```
                             Fault Domain           Update Domain
server_iis1                        0                        0
server_iis2                        1                        1
```

As i know ,Fault Domain in reality is a rack, however the following points confuses me :

1. If I loose entirely Fault Domain 0 ,then server_iis1 is gone ?
   Where the 2nd instance of server_iis1 is located that should be up and running in case of a rack failure(Fault Domain 0) that will provide me with 99.95% SLA ?
2. Likewise, for server_iis2 , if i loose Fault Domain 1 ,how server_iis2 is supposed to be up and running ?
3. Server_iis1 & Server_iis2 are completely 2 different VMs with diferrent data and customers to serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fault domains are designed to protect your workload (applications running on a vm) in case of unexpected hardware failures. In your example above iis1 and iis2 are two separate VMs running in the same physical datacenter (availability zone)but are in different fault domains. What this means is that if for some reason some physical component of the vm's support infrastructure fails (rack power supply, switch, physical host, etc) the other iis vm will remain up because it's sitting on a different cluster of hardware (fault domain) in the same datacenter.

One thing that is not as clear for many individuals is that your application must be smart enough to run on both machines simultaneously. If I have one app (excel as a very basic example (just humor me)) on iis1 and a different app (powerpoint) on iis2, if iis1 goes down you lose access to the app (excel) until the vm fails over to another host which may take a few minutes. And vice verse for iis2, if it went down you would lose (powerpoint). To truly make fault domains work you would need excel and powerpoint running on both iis1 & iis2 so if one vm fails the other can still server the application and of course your application would need to be smart enough to handle the failure/failover.

Soooo fault domains protect against unexpected unpredicted failures in the infrastructure.

Update domains are designed to ensure that during maintenance windows (either customer or Microsoft initiated) that we don't reboot/update all machines at once.

As an example, If I had 5 front end web servers connected to 5 backend servers I would put the 5 front end servers in the same update domain so that they will never be rebooted at the same time ensuring I can always serve web traffic. That also goes for my backend servers. I'd put them in an update domain together to ensure that they all never get rebooted at the same time. Doing this ensures that I keep the server(s) running though degraded during maintenance windows.

Availability Sets do provide an SLA of 99.95%.
Availability Zones provide an SLA of 99.99%

Deploying your vm into an Availability zone will replicate your vm to another physical datacenter (zone). This failover happens automatically without the customer having to do anything if something breaks.

Avail set is cheaper to deploy availability zones cost more because not only do you have the vm costs you have costs associated with data replication between zones but we're talking pennies on the dollar.

Hope that helps